# How can I implement the NavigationBottomView?

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm getting mad trying to implement the NavigationBottomView.
The problem is that there are no updated examples or tutorials of the NavigationBottomView, like the one described on the material.io guidelines, with all the animations.
Am I missing something or Google is Just providing the documentation without examples?
I really want to learn how to use this component in the best possible way.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use this library: [link](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)
A custom view component that mimics the new Material Design Bottom Navigation pattern.It is actively maintained, you could do a pull request and add features if desired.It also as some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of navigation is just one activity with several fragments.You need to add some dependencies in gradle and in the main activity xml add the widget BottomNavigationView. Look this example: http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/